# Android how to highlight drawable of selected action bar tab

Tags: android, android-xml, android-tabs

I am looking to add action bar tabs with icons. I have achieved the following.

[image]

In this, how do I make the selected tab icon orange i.e. if the first tab is selected, the first icon is orange, while the others stay gray and so on.
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18909349/1276374

Comment: There is way to customize the tab text color (if you had) .. not sure if you can have different color icons based on tab states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution is. You must create an icon in white and orange and put it in your drawables folder and in the onCreate method of your currently tab add this here:

```
//TabActivity.onCreate()
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
TabHost.TabSpec spec;
Intent intent;

intent = new Intent().setClass(this,YourClass.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab_name").setIndicator("Tab Text", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_dialer)).setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Then, you need to add ic_tab_dialer.xml to res/drawable/ directory with this content:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_selected_dialer" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_unselected_dialer" />
</selector>
```

I hope this helps.