# How to highlight a Tab when Notification received

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost, android-notifications

I have implemented `Tab host` with the `Notification`. Now My problem is: there are 3 tabs like Food, Health and Service. If i receive a Food Notification How to highlight the Food Tab automatically

Comment: You just want to highlight or show its content also???

Comment: Both first need to highlight then showing contents

Comment: check out [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24836021/2715073) might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this :

**First Step:** Create a broadcast receiver which you can call when you click on notification

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,
                PushNotificationBroadcastReceiver.class); // this is the broadcast receiver which will be called 
                PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                1, notificationIntent, 0);
```

**Second Step:** in onReceive() method put below line:

```
TabActivity tabs = (TabActivity) getParent();
    tabs.getTabHost().setCurrentTab(2);  //2 means the position of tab which you want to show
```

That's it.

Comment: Yes i am doing like this but Content is displaying in particular tab but it is not highlighting

Comment: check out [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24836021/2715073) might help you

Comment: tabs.getTabHost().setCurrentTab(2);  for this just set the colour for tab 2 and update the code it may solve my problem

Comment: It is solved but my problem if notification arrives how to refresh the activity..? if refresh the activity my problem will solve 100%

Answer (score 0):

For switching to some other tab than the default one you need to put this code on the onClick or whatever triggers the action

TabActivity tabs = (TabActivity) getParent();
    tabs.getTabHost().setCurrentTab(x);

Just replace x with the tab which you would like to navigate to and make sure to change the variable names and class names as per your project.
Hope it helps you ;)