# Android: background color when menu item is pressed

Tags: android, background-color, menuitem

I'm trying to change the background color to the menu item when it is pressed. Change the background color but not the color when pressed.

WHISED:

- Background: dark gray
- Background pressed: orange

OBTAINED:

- Background: dark gray
- Background pressed: blue (default Android)

What I can do? Thanks

[image]

**Styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme2" parent="android:Theme.Holo">  
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyApp.PopupMenu</item>
</style>

<style name="MyApp.PopupMenu" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_item_selector</item>
</style>
```

**menu_item_selector.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_item_fondo_pressed" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_item_fondo_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_item_fondo"/>

</selector>
```

Comment: Refer this Question

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18909273/how-to-change-color-of-selected-tab][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18909273/how-to-change-color-of-selected-tab

Comment: I have used ActionBar Style Generator. But I don't know what drawables I need

Answer (score 5):

Little late answer, but found solution for the problem.

In *styles.xml* where You have your *AppTheme*:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/ListViewStyle</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/ListViewStyle</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/PopupMenuTextAppearanceLarge</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">@style/PopupMenuTextAppearanceSmall</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/PopupMenuTextAppearanceLarge</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">@style/PopupMenuTextAppearanceSmall</item>
</style>
```

The *popupMenuStyle* is for popupMenu itself, in this case we can change there **unselected** background in *popupBackground* item, like this (but You already know that):

```
<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/selector_popup_menu_bg</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color_white</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selector_popup_menu_dropdown</item>
</style>
```

There are also *textColor* and *dropDownSelector* items, which aren't doing anything on devices I have tested, but I change these here too just in case, because parent (*Widget.PopupMenu*) uses them too.

The way to **properly** change these items is to change them in *AppTheme* like I've shown above in *AppTheme* code. I won't show code for textAppearances, because it is not the subject.

The reason I've added each of these items twice (with and without "android:" prefix) is to make it work both on 5.0 and pre-lollipop devices. The only exception is *popupMenuStyle* with only needs item without "android:” prefix, if you’re using the framework version of `Popup`, but if you use the `support.v7` version, then you need `android:popupMenuStyle` ([see this StackOverflow answer for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40684110/2684)).

So to have different background of item selected we simply change it in *dropDownListViewStyle* (I have additionaly added *divider*):

```
<style name="ListViewStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selector_popup_menu_dropdown</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@color/text_color_white</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
</style>
```

The interesting part is *listSelector*, which is the background of selected item. If we would add there only @color then selected item wouldn't be properly invalidated (it will stay selected even if you move selection out of it), to make it properly instead of color, selector needs to be used:

**selector_popup_menu_dropdown.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />

<!-- Even though these two point to the same resource, have two states so the drawable will invalidate itself when coming out of pressed state. -->
<item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/gray_btn_bg_color" />
<item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false"                              android:drawable="@color/gray_btn_bg_color" />
<item android:state_focused="true"                                android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/gray_btn_bg_color" />
<item android:state_focused="false"                               android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/gray_btn_bg_color" />
<item android:state_focused="true"                                                             android:drawable="@color/gray_btn_bg_color" />
```

A little too long explaination for such trival thing, but we made it till the end. Yaay!

Comment: Thank you! Your experiment and explanation is very useful for me :)