# Popup menu style issue

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio

I am developing one app in which I have a list and a popup menu in it. But my app has black background color and text color is white. But my popup menu back color coming is white and text color is white. I have tried all posible ways but its not working. Here is my code.

Style.xml

```
<attr name="iconColor" format="reference" />
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/back_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/holo_orange_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/White</item>

    <item name="android:textSize">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="iconColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/back_color</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/holo_red_light</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >

    <item name="android:panelBackground">@color/back_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>

<style name="StyledScrollerTextAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/White</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12dp</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.TextAppearance.Subtitle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/White</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">10dp</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:panelBackground">@color/back_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/White</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBarCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
</style>
```

Below is recycler view adapter

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemHolder itemHolder, int i) {
    Song localItem = arraylist.get(i);

    itemHolder.title.setText(localItem.title);
    itemHolder.artist.setText(localItem.artistName);


    setOnPopupMenuListener(itemHolder, i);

}

private void setOnPopupMenuListener(ItemHolder itemHolder, final int position) {

    itemHolder.popupMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Context wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(mContext, R.style.PopupMenu);
            final PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu(wrapper, v);

            menu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.popup_play:

                            break;
                        case R.id.popup_next:

                            break;

                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            menu.inflate(R.menu.popup_song);

            menu.show();
        }
    });
}
```

Please help me with it.

Answer (score 0):

> After reading comments, you need a [contextual menu](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html).

Inherit your `PopupMenu` from `Widget.PopupMenu`.

```
   <style name="AppTheme.PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/yourcolor</item>
    </style>
```

I would suggest wrap your toolbar in `AppBarLayout` and in `AppBarLayout theme` set your menu style.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Here are styles.

```
   <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- text color for toolbar and popup menu-->
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/AppTheme.PopupMenu</item>
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/AppTheme.PopupMenu</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
        <!-- background color of popup menu-->
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/colorBlack</item>
    </style>
```

Finally, create your popup menu with `AppBarLayout` context.

```
   AppBarLayout bar= (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        PopupMenu p = new PopupMenu(bar.getContext(), findViewById(item.getItemId()));
```

For more information, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40671629/change-popup-menu-background-color) answer.

Comment: Its list view not seprate button. can you help me in it.

Comment: What do you mean by list view? and button? `@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu` is android's style for popup menus, which opens like a list (if you are thinking about that)

Comment: I have list in which i have popup menu. Each line has list. let take eg. delete, share etc for each line. have created popup in list. You can see in my code there is Recycle adapter. which is binding.

Comment: you need `contextual menu`,  not popup menu.

Comment: can you share snapshot?