# Menu item with background color

Tags: android

I wanted to create a popup menu like following,

[image]

I used `actionLayout` attribute like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_1"
        android:title="@string/title"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/item_1" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_2"
        android:title="@string/title"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/item_2" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_3"
        android:title="@string/title"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/item_3" />
</menu>
```

where my `item_1` layout will be like,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="100dp"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#fff9c4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageTemp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageTemp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image"
        android:padding="@dimen/dp8"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_remove_red_eye_24px"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And I have used this code to create `PopupMenu`,

```
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(Objects.requireNonNull(fragment.getActivity()), v);
popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_attachment, popupMenu.getMenu());
popupMenu.show();
```

But unfortunately I couldn't achieve what I want. The current output is,

[image]

Comment: Not exactly the same, but you can get hints of how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454995/popupmenu-with-icons)

Comment: Also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40671629/change-popup-menu-background-color/45779607) one

Comment: I think You need create a Custom [`PopupWindow`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15455081/4168607) for this

Comment: @ADM PopupWindow to view Anchor always bottom to the view... but I want it to top of the view.. is it possible?

Comment: I'm not sure about this part . Try dig into `showAtLocation` .