# Styling tab indicator or background color of selected tab

Tags: android, tabs, styling

I am trying to use the code generated from Android Action Bar Style Generator.for creating and tabs in my application.but Unfortunately stopped error is being shown..Maybe some issue of theme..I have also added:
`android:theme="@style/Theme.Example"` in manifest.

Please help me. I am a beginner in android.

**LogCat:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.priyankagupta.tabbing/com.example.priyankagupta.tabbing.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity. at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
```

Comment: It won't work like this. Show the XML containing Tab.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change color of Selected Tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18909273/how-to-change-color-of-selected-tab)

Comment: Thanks....I got something..will try..hope will be helpful to me

Comment: In your manifest, you're using different theme. Use **AppTheme** there.

Comment: yes..this was the issue..Thanks a lot..........

Comment: Glad to help. In future, try to explain your question by giving as much details as possible (related code, error logs, etc) in order to get quick answers. :)

Comment: It's hard to tell why it's not showing up without looking at the code. Can you show your `Styles.xml` & `Manifest.xml`?

Comment: I can explain but commenting under the question is getting too long & your reputation is too low to chat [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71661/android-discussions). You can do one thing, if it's just a demo application then you can mail it to me as a .rar/.zip and I'll check it for you.

Comment: actually in Mainactivity class it was hidden somehow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `android` tag like:

```
<item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TabText</item>
```

because you are using support library.

And also try to use `parent` of `MyTheme.ActionBar.TabText` as:

```
parent="Widget.AppCompat.Base.ActionBar.TabText"
```

Comment: NO its not working,...Because may be i have not used this style anywhere in other class.Where i have to apply this style

Comment: It included in your `MyTheme`, and I suppose you have set `MyTheme` in your manifest

Comment: yes i have android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >in menifest file. and my theme is mentioned in sttyles.xml

Comment: Can you try the modified answer